# How to save data from textbox to datagrid in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to make a simple application in UWP for write in a textbox and save it (with a button) into a datagrid...

i don't find how to make this and i really new (noob) using this platform.

this the only i found about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox?view=winrt-19041#use-textbox-for-data-input-in-a-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to save data from textbox to datagrid in UWP

For your scenario, you could make a string collection and bind it to  `DataGrid` item source like the following.

**CodeBehind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private ObservableCollection<string> Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private void dataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = Items;
    }

    private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentTextBox.Text))
        {
            Items.Add(ContentTextBox.Text);
            ContentTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        }
       
    }
}
```

**Xaml Code**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="ContentTextBox" />
        <Button
            x:Name="SubmitButton"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Click="SubmitButton_Click"
            Content="Submit" />
    </Grid>

    <controls:DataGrid
        x:Name="dataGrid"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="12"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
        AlternatingRowForeground="Gray"
        AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"
        AreRowGroupHeadersFrozen="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="True"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        CanUserSortColumns="False"
        ColumnHeaderHeight="32"
        FrozenColumnCount="0"
        GridLinesVisibility="None"
        HeadersVisibility="Column"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        IsReadOnly="False"
        Loaded="dataGrid_Loaded"
        MaxColumnWidth="400"
        RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
        RowGroupHeaderPropertyNameAlternative="Range"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                Binding="{Binding}"
                Header="Content"
                Tag="text" />
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```